# How to add multiple class names dynamically in jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Right now I am only adding the location at 0 index as the class name
li.req.disabled(class="#{artist.locations[0]}")

ie.
class="Delhi"

But I want to add all the names in artists.locations array in the class name.

e.g. if I have three cities A, B, C in artist.locations I want something like
class="A B C"

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade accepts an array for classes :

```
div(class=artist.locations)
```

will generate

```
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

if `artist.locations` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`

(also note that your code contains a `#` before the class name which is probably incorrect)